# uso del condicional if para evaluar una variable

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.7

Estoy evaluando una variable con el condicional if, le paso por teclado un "@" y "." y la respuesta que me da por consola es que toma la rama del else y no entiendo porque ya que cuando le paso por teclado el "@" y el caracter "." es verdadero por lo tanto deberia de toma la rama del if.

```
a= raw_input("Ingresa el texto: ")

if a == "@" and a == ".":
    print "si estan los elementos"

else:
    print "no se encuentran"
```

Comment: No está claro si lo que le pasas por teclado es la cadena `"@."` y quieres que en ese caso entre en el `if`, o si quieres que entre también cuando por teclado le pasas solo `"@"` o solo `"."` Si es lo segundo, debes cambiar el `and` por un `or`. Un caracter no puede ser _a la vez_ dos cosas, como le pides con el `and`.

Comment: ok amigo muchas gracias, ya lo entendi :D

Answer (score 1):

Esta evaluación nunca resultará verdadera `if a == "@" and a == ".":` porque *a* no puede ser igual a `@` y, a la vez, igual a `.`.

Necesitas usar una función que busque esos caracteres: [find()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-find/), que devuelve la posición del caracter que buscas (0 o mayor) o -1 si no lo encuentra.

```
a= raw_input("Ingresa el texto: ")

if a.find("@") != -1 and a.find(".") != -1:
    print "si estan los elementos"

else:
    print "no se encuentran"
```

Si lo que quieres es validar una dirección de correo electrónico, entonces intenta con [email-validator](https://pypi.org/project/email-validator/)

Answer (score 1):

Esto sucede porque estás evaluando una cadena de caracteres, también conocida como string. No es lo mismo **a="@."** que **a="@"** o **a="."**

Tu esperas que una misma variable tenga 2 valores posibles, lo cual no se puede realizar en una misma instancia. Por ejemplo, no es posible que una taza contenga "café" y "leche" en una misma instancia, tendrías que vaciar taza de café y volver a llenarla con leche, pero no puedes tener las 2 al mismo tiempo en la misma taza. Lo mismo pasa con las variables. Por tanto, tu IF dice lo siguiente:

> Si A es igual a "@" y A es igual a "." entonces sí están los elementos

Pero A nunca podrá tener estos 2 valores al mismo tiempo, o es @ o es ., pero nunca ambos en simultáneo, por lo cual esa condición NUNCA se cumplirá. Ahora debes estar pensando que A puede ser igual a "@.", y estarías en lo cierto, pero "@." es diferente a "@" y a ".", como sería distinto un "café con leche" a un "café" y a la "leche" ¿comprendes la diferencia?

Como lo puedes solucionar?, pues de muchas maneras dependiendo lo que realmente quieras conseguir. Si deseas ingresar más de 1 caracter y encontrar si esa cadena tiene ambos caracteres, pues puedes hacer lo siguiente:

> if "@" in a and "." in a: print "si estan los elementos"

Para finalizar, es importante que comprendas que los strings son arrays de caracteres. Por ejemplo, la palabra "hola" es un array compuesto por "h","o","l","a".

Espero haberte ayudado con tu problema.

Comment: Exelente explicacion amigo lo entendi muy bien se hizo la luz, agradecido!!